Find a function $f$ such that $f(x+2) = C_1 + C_2f(x)$ for any $x$
I'm looking for a way to find a function f such that $f(x+2)=C_1+C_2f(x)$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}, x>0$ where $C_1, C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
I know that for the constraint $g(x+2)=Cg(x)$ we can use $g(x)=C^{\frac{1}{2}x}k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$.
And for $h(x+2) = C + h(x)$ we can obviously use $h(x)=\frac{1}{2}Cx+k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$.
However I was unable so far to find any suitable function $f$ or any method to find it or prove it doesn't exist.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could find a function f that satisfies the constraints or any pointers on how to find it.

Try to take $g(x) = f(x) - a$ and insert this into the equation and solve for $a$ such that you are left with $g(x+2) = C_2g(x)$ which you know how to solve. This is possible as long as $C_2 \not = 1$. And for $C_2=1$ you already have a solution.

Hint: if you differentiate the equation you end up with
$$f'(x+2)=C_2f'(x)$$
so now you are back to your known functional equation but for $f'$...
Can you take it from here?

This is a great hint! I was able to apply my example of $g(x + 2) = Cg(x)$ with $f'$ as $g$ and calculate the primitive to obtain $f$. Thanks a lot!

You are welcome!
